# Como operar sobre o contador de um while em cada iteração do loop

Tags: python, string, for, while, operadores

Desculpe minha ignorância estou começando a aprender python agora, minha duvida é: Como eu consigo gerar um resultado em cada iteração de um while.

```
valor= input('digite o numero desejado:')

contador = 0

while contador <=100:

print(contador, '% de', valor,' é igual a:', **'RESULTADO'**)
contador= contador + 1
```

Quero achar uma função ou comando que print o termo RESULTADO para todos os valores de 1 a 100.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, consegui terminar meu projeto e ainda aprendi algo novo, nem sei como agradecer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para obter o valor e [f-strig](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) para simplificar a composição do texto.

```
valor= int(input('digite o numero desejado:'))

#No caso 0% e 100% são valores redundante pois 0% sempre vai ser 0 e 100% é o valor da entrada
for p, r in [(i, valor * i / 100) for i in range(1,100)]:
  print(f'{p}% de {valor} é igual a {r}')
```

ou então:

```
valor= int(input('digite o numero desejado:'))

#No caso 0% e 100% são valores redundante pois 0% sempre vai ser 0 e 100% é o valor da entrada
for r in [(i, valor * i / 100) for i in range(1,100)]:
  print(f'{r[0]}% de {valor} é igual a {r[1]}')
```

Teste ambos os exemplos em  Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/ExcellentAdvancedSlope

List comprehension é uma maneira de criar listas onde os elementos são obtidos ou operações aplicadas a membros de outra sequência iterável ou satisfazendo uma condição determinada.

As strings-f são literais de strings prefixados pela letra 'f' ou 'F' onde expressões aparecem entre chaves `{`e `}` é uma expressão da linguagem a ser avaliada.

Comment: Quem votou negativo gostaria de explicar o que tem de errado na resposta para que possa ser melhorada.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas vou estudar sobre esses assuntos que foram abordados.

Comment: @ViniciusSartori qualquer coisa é só fazer uma nova pergunta que a comunidade sempre está disposta a ajudar.

Comment: Augusto você saberia explicar como eu poderia agora " pesquisar " um determinado valor dentre esses valores, vamos dizer que no final do código eu crie um input que eu desejaria encontrar um numero especifico como por exemplo.  

' mostre o valor de 31% apenas ' mas que a lista de resultado anterior não sumisse.

ps: só mudei o  range para rodar o código, porque eu queria que o valor de 100% fosse mostrado no final, mesmo sabendo que é o mesmo valor do numero do input.

Comment: @ViniciusSartori Seria `print(valor * número_desejado / 100)` no caso 31% seria `print(valor * 31 /100)`.

Answer (score 1):

Um simples cálculo matemático já resolve o problema para encontrar o resultado. Basta dividir o valor por 100 e depois multiplicar pelo `contador` que você obtém o resultado.

```
resultado = valor / 100 * porcentagem
```

É possível melhorar seu código substituindo o laço `while` por um `for...range`. Dessa forma, você reduz a quantidade de linhas que seriam gastas criando o contador.

```
valor = int(input('Digite o numero desejado: '))

for contador in range(0, 101):
    print(str(contador) + '% de', valor, 'é igual a:', valor / 100 * contador)
```

E o último problema é que o valor que você obtém do usuário é uma string e não um número inteiro. O Python não realiza cálculos com valores strings, então você precisará converter o valor obtido em um `int()` como no código acima.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era mais simples do que eu esperava, sem palavras pela resposta tão rápido, já posso ir dormir tranquilo sem essa duvida. Vlw mesmo.

Comment: Quem votou negativo gostaria de explicar o que tem de errado na resposta para que possa ser melhorada.